# Extern inheritance duplicate symbol errors, what is going on?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, extern

I have a question about the use of extern and inheritance. I'm coding an iOS app in Objective C using X-Code.

I have two hypothetical classes B and C which both inherit from class A.

Now class A imports a class called Constraints in it's header file like this: **#import "Constraints.h"**. In the **.H** header  of constraints are declared various **extern NSInteger const VAR_NAME** values above the **@interface Constraints : NSObject**  but below the imports. In the .M implementation the externs are initialised for example as follows **NSInteger const VAR_NAME = 1**. Again this is placed below the imports but above the **@implementation Constraints** line. This file aims to hold app wide global constraints.

However, when doing this, on build XCode reports a mach-o-linker error for duplicate symbols in class B and C for each and every variable declared as extern in the Constraints files.

So what I did then was remove the import of the class Constraints from the parent class A, and instead import it directly into classes B and C. However, I get the same issue.

I've been bashing my head against the table on this one for some hours now, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the code that is producing the error? This seems right to me and is usually just caused by a typo. I've read other posts where the people simply imported the .m file instead of the .h file by accident, which commonly causes this error.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'll try and make a small example and test  as the code is very large.

Comment: Ah my simple example had no issues so my model of how things should work seem correct. The child classes also need to import the constraints class as this is not inherited.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. If I was helpful, upvotes are always appreciated!